# Capitalization of bpm/BPM meaning beats per minute

Tags: capitalization, abbreviations, dictionaries

The Oxford English Dictionary defines **"bpm"** as an abbreviation of "beats per minute" and gives the example:

> a pulse rate of 40 bpm

Is there an explanation for the curious feature that this abbreviation is set in lowercase?

Comment: Not sure how it is curious. Abrreviations for grams, meters, liters, and so on are always set in lowercase. And minutes and hours and seconds, too. And V, A, J etc. are only capitalized because they are named after people.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Can you explain why you find it curious? First of all, *bpm* is not always set in lowercase. Second, most everyday measures are put in lowercase, e.g. *kwh*, *mpg*, *cpm*, whereas others depend on industry or professional conventions, e.g. *VO2 max*, *bp*, *VaR*, etc.

Answer (score 1):

This is really a question of style. Abbreviations (or, in this case, ***initialisms***) are not necessarily capitalised, especially when all of the words would be spelled out without a capital letter: there's an example in the question where "beats per minute" is spelled out with minuscule letters.

Most initialisms either have a proper noun as at least one of the words, which may cause the whole to be capitalised, or the term is important in the document (eg [Wikipedia's example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialism#Casing_of_expansions) of *congestive heart failure [CHF]*). It's very unlikely that a term like "beats per minute" needs to be made prominent in a sentence within a text. Setting it in capitals could upset the balance of the typesetting, and lowercase is easier than using small caps <sub><sup>BPM</sup></sub>.

If it might get lost, for example when filling in a form, it might well be capitalised.

```
   Heart rate: ________ BPM
```

There is an additional set of initialisms — acronyms, which can be pronounced as words — and where these are common nouns they are customarily set in lower-case: *scuba, laser, radar, sonar* and the like.

Answer (score 1):

In general, units should not be considered as abbreviations, but *symbols* (see, for example, the [SI brochure](http://www.bipm.org/en/si/si_brochure/)). So, for instance, the capital letter A is not the abbreviation of the unit ampere (ampere, with a lowercase initial, is the unit; Ampère, with a capital initial, is the scientist), but rather its symbol; similarly, J is the symbol of the unit joule, not its abbreviation.

That said, it should be noted that bpm is not a recognized unit in the SI (an acceptable unit would be min^-1), but treating it as any other unit can do no harm.