# Should TPS (transactions per second) be upper or lower case

Tags: american-english, abbreviations

If one wants to write shorthand for transactions per second what would be correct casing? TPS or tps?

- As SI unit, s is always lowercase and thus I believe it should be written as "tps".
- On other hand, it as an abbreviation and thus it deserves uppercase "TPS" treatment.

Comment: There's a very [similar question about BPM](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/180421/capitalization-of-bpm-bpm-meaning-beats-per-minute). Does that help here?

Comment: Being an abbreviation does not grant "all caps" treatment unless the words are individually capitalized. For example, abbr. is the abbreviation for "abbreviation."

Comment: @AndrewLeach Yes, it answers my question perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: @OrangeWombat While abbreviations aren't necessarily capitalized, initialism usually are.

Comment: @Barmar - thank you for pointing that out, I hadn't realized the difference.